# How do I confirm my selection in UIPickerView with a done button?

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I apologise for this question, other questions are either outdated or are about embedding buttons within a UIPickerView

I have a UIPickerView which displays 3 strings; once my user has selected the string he wishes to select, I want him to hit a done button (which is not embedded in the UIPickerView itself; but appears separately).

```
let strings = ["1", "2", "3"]

fileprivate let pickerView: UIPickerView = {
       let pv = UIPickerView()
        pv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return pv
    }()

override func viewDidLoad() {
pickerView.delegate = self
pickerView.dataSource = self

}

    let button: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        btn.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(donePressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        return btn
    }()
    @objc func donePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Done pressed")
        //Pressing this should print whichever row is currently selected
    }

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return strings.count
    }



}

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate {


    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        strings[row]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@objc func donePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Done pressed")
        print(strings[pickerView!.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking for something useful in the documentation. Ah, here it is:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview/1614369-selectedrow

So. Have your button call the picker view's `selectedRow(inComponent:)`. There is only one component so you will pass `0`. The return value is the *index* (the selected row). Use that as an index into `strings` if you want to know the actual *value* (the string).